# Placing Array of objects into mssql db from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I'm attempting to place a decently sized array of objects into a db and I've got the code written that will do it and several records ARE actually written to the DB, however something about the formatting is causing the function to throw errors.

One of those errors that I've seen on multiple attempts to fix this issue is:

`"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."`

another is

`"Incorrect syntax near 's'."`

When I initially open the array I'm attempting to place into the DB I get an alert from VSCode about symbols that needed to be removed but I am not able to get the error verbatim at the moment and don't know how to replicate the message. Regardless it has no effect on if it will add all entries or not.

My question is what about my objects could cause this kind of weird issue and what kinds of things could I fix keeping in mind that some of the records are actually being added. Thank you!

Also what is the best/easiest way for bulk adding items to a DB programmatically? ATM I'm just doing INSERT INTO query.

Comment: Since you're not showing us any code I suppose we have to guess... Sounds like you're concatenating strings to build SQL queries and one of the values being sent probably contains an `'` character which breaks the query. That process of concatenating query code and user data is called SQL Injection, [don't do that](https://xkcd.com/327/). Consider [parameterized queries/prepared statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#prepared-statement) or even [bulk insert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk-table-options-callback).

Comment: Thank you, I was vague due to me not knowing if my employer finds the info I'm working with to be sensitive. At any rate, your suggestion of bulk inserting was what I needed and I learned how SQL injection attacks work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.